# How to get Pubnub JS history messages

Tags: javascript, pubnub

I am currently trying to get the history of a channel in js, here is my current code:

*Send message*

```
function sendMessage(text){
    box=$('box')
    box.innerHTML = ('' + text).replace(/[<>]/g, '') + '<br>' + box.innerHTML
}
```

Here is my current code for getting history

```
pubnub.fetchMessages(
    {
      channels: ['ch-1'],
      end: '15343325004275466',
      count: 20
    },
    (status, response) => {
      sendMessage(response.messages[0])
    }
);
```

But it is not working. can someone please help

Comment: If you tried Darryn's solution below but still not working, it might be a race condition. Are you publishing the message and immediately trying to fetch the message? Because the operations are async and the message has to be persisted across many nodes in the network (globally), it might not have been persisted within the time you are fetching. There isn't any real-world use case for publish/fetch anyways, so I assume this is just testing PN message persisence. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this syntax:

```js
pubnub.fetchMessages( // Get the last 10 messages sent in the chat.
{
   channels: ['ch-1'],
   count: 10,
},
function (status, response) {
   if (response.channels[channel] && channel in response.channels) {
      response.channels[channel].forEach((message) => {
         console.log(message);
      });
   }
});
```

Another possibility is you have persistence disabled in your admin dashboard (or the period of retention is set too short so you have no stored messages to retrieve)

Comment: I tried your answer and it didn't work, when I tried to alert (I am not using an ide so no 'console.log' for me) it didn't alert anything, and I turned on persistence, so I think there is an error with the code

Comment: How are you publishing messages?  Your sendMessage function does not publish any messages to PubNub

Comment: Yes, that's what I use for the front end, as that's the function I use in the PubNub publish function